# Refresh page when press enter

Tags: jquery, refresh, imagebutton, enter

My code has few `<asp:ImageButton>` . But I want to make when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, not others change but only **submit** button works . Now, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in my code , `.calendar` class button works and calendar come out.

**jquery**

```
$('form').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $('.submit').submit();
                //return false;
            }
        });
```

**.aspx**

```
<div id="form">
<div id="main">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="Button1" CssClass="calbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Show Calendar" AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <div class="calendar">
                    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" Visible="False">
                    </asp:Calendar>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageView" CssClass="submit" runat="server" onclick="ImageView_Click"  AutoPostBack="True" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is your `form`..??

Comment: @outlooker     form is in out of this `<div id="main">` . I skipped it for simple code. I fixed it

Comment: should'nt u be having a `<form>` tag rather than a div with attribute `id="form"`

Comment: @outlooker     thanks for your advice :) and How about my jQuery code? I'm not sure what tag I should put in `$('')` < here.

Comment: so u want to submit ur form when the enter key is pressed right..??

Comment: @Outlooker       yes, :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work for u mate.. :)

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
        <div id="main">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="Button1" CssClass="calbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Show Calendar" AutoPostBack="True" />
                        <div class="calendar">
                            <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" Visible="False"></asp:Calendar>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageView" CssClass="submit" runat="server" onclick="ImageView_Click" AutoPostBack="True" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Script**

```
$('#myForm input').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $("#myForm").submit();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks so much! :D but can you help me more? I want to do click event with `ImageView` button. For instance, when I press **enter** key in the screen, `ImageView' asp button click not `Calendar1` button. I tried `$("#myForm").submit();` to `$("#ImageView").submit();` but `Calendal1` button clicked.

Comment: try `$("#ImageView").trigger('click');`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap in asp:panel and set defaultbutton.

Comment: Can you tell me more detail? wrap what? and where set default button?

Comment: Wrap you controls in asp:panel and defaultbutton is a property of panel.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it still doesn't work. It's first time to use **<asp:Panel>** so little confused. ` `<asp:Panel wrap="true" runat="server" DefaultButton="ImageView">` `<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageView" CssClass="searchbutton" runat="server" onclick="ImageView_Click"  AutoPostBack="True" />` `</asp:Panel>` is it right?